# Is there a Elixir equivalent of Rails `try` function?

Tags: ruby, elixir

In Rails you can do something like:

`@user.try(:contact_info).try(:phone_number)`

Which will return the `phone_number` if the `@user` and `contact_info` are both not nil. If one of those are nil, the expression will return nil.

I want to know what is the most idiomatic way to do this in Elixir, knowing that `@user` and `contact_info` are **structs**.

Comment: I think you can just use pattern matching to handle the situations when there is and there is not `phone_number`

Comment: @JustMichael You should make that an answer, as it's the best solution.

Comment: But there should be a one liner solution.

Answer (score 6):

I think one way to do that is to go with pattern matching so it would be something like this:

```
case user do
  %{contact_info: %{phone_number: phone_number}} when phone_number != nil -> 
    #do something when the phone number is present
  _ -> 
    #do something when the phone number is absent
end
```

Comment: Whether you pattern-match with a case statement or on a function head, this is probably the Best Way™.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Testing my suggestion to use `with`, I realize it won't work as it short circuits on match error, but you'll have `UndefinedFunctionError` on nil. So I removed that part. I'd go with pattern matching, as @JustMichael suggested.

If you control the definition of the structs, a default value in the struct may help.

```
defmodule ContactInfo do
  defstruct phone_number: nil
end

defmodule User do
  defstruct contact_info: %ContactInfo{}
end

iex> user = %User{}
%User{contact_info: %ContactInfo{phone_number: nil}}
iex> user.contact_info.phone_number
nil
```

Someone could still purposely set `:contact_info` to nil, but consider just letting it crash… :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_in` from Kernel:

```
iex(2)> user = %{contact_info: %{name: "Bob"}}
%{contact_info: %{name: "Bob"}}
iex(3)> get_in(user, [:contact_info, :name])
"Bob"
iex(4)> user2 = %{}
%{}
iex(5)> get_in(user2, [:contact_info, :name])
nil
iex(6)> user3 = %{contact_info: %{}}
%{contact_info: %{}}
iex(7)> get_in(user3, [:contact_info, :name])
nil
```

Note that this will won't work with Ecto models/structs, but plain maps are fine.

Comment: `get_in` does not work with Structs. In this case it works because `user` is a Map.

Comment: I have just put the structs in bold in my question, so it's more clear. Thanks

Comment: Anyway, `Map.from_struct\1` is here to help. But the issue is that it won't work with lists, while in many languages (JS, Ruby), `get_in(object, [:key, :other_key, 3]` would return the third value of the `object.key.other_key` list. Sad :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably no, Elixir is not object oriented, so you are calling known functions on defined modules (if the function/module is not defined then the code don't even compile).

For successive call on functions with the pipe operator, where the result can be `nil` at any step, I think a single big `try` block is suffice. Or you can try the `pipe_while` macros from this library https://github.com/batate/elixir-pipes

Comment: `elixir-pipes` seems to do kind of what I want, except we need to give a pattern that matches success.  I would like the opposite, something that does not match nil.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are no baked in solution in Elixir. So I rolled up my own.

```
defmodule Maybe do
  def and_then(nil, _), do: nil
  def and_then(val,fnc), do: fnc.(val)
  def and_get(struct, key), do: struct |> and_then(&(Map.get(&1, key)))
end

no_user = nil
without_contact_info = %{contact_info: nil}
with_contact_info = %{contact_info: %{address: "here"}}

no_user |> Maybe.and_then(&(Map.get(&1, :contact_info))) |> Maybe.and_then(&(Map.get(&1, :address)))
#> nil
without_contact_info |> Maybe.and_then(&(Map.get(&1, :contact_info))) |> Maybe.and_then(&(Map.get(&1, :address)))
#> nil
with_contact_info |> Maybe.and_then(&(Map.get(&1, :contact_info))) |> Maybe.and_then(&(Map.get(&1, :address)))
#> "here"

# or with the less generic `and_get`

with_contact_info |> Maybe.and_get(:contact_info) |> Maybe.and_get(:address)
#> "here"
```

It's probably not idiomatic Elixir however it cleans up my code.

Comment: In this particular case you're doing a lot of defensive coding. That's definitely not the idiomatic way in Elixir.  The idiomatic way in Elixir is "let it crash". If either your user or contact_info are nil, how will you recover from that?  What's the else path in that case?

Comment: Maybe something like "N/A".  `with_contact_info |> Maybe.and_get(:contact_info) |> Maybe.and_get(:address)  && "N/A"`.In that case I want to display it in a view, letting it crash is not what I want.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what I mean by "let it crash".  I'm not saying the whole application will crash--solely the process that's trying to extract the information. Basically you want to start the process to extract the data you're looking for from a supervisor. Then if the data isn't there, let the process crash.  See this: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LetItCrash for more on the subject.

Comment: I understand your point,  I know about the let it crash idea and Erlang's OTP. However in my case, `:contact_info` being nil is not an exceptional case, it's a real use case. It's possible that the user didn't enter it's contact info before.

Comment: Avoiding idiomatic Elixir and rolling your own should be a major red flag: I agree that this probably isn't a situation that you need to crash on, but solving this idomatically isn't hard.  The real issue here is an indecisive API- either write a function on the top level module that does the pattern matching (`User.get_address(user)`), or use the top level struct's default value to ~ guarantee the presence of the inner, and crash if someone hoses that, as suggested in one of the other answers.

Comment: Coming from the Ruby world, I can't see anything wrong with @Martinos implementation.

Comment: How can't there be a code to write that there are two cases: either a variable has X value, and we want to transform it into Y, or it is `nil` and it should stay `nil`. Nothing *unexpected*, everything's under control! Kind of like a monad in the Haskell world.

Answer (score 0):

```
defmodule ContactInfo do
  defstruct phone_number: nil
end

defmodule User do
  defstruct contact_info: nil
end

defmodule Test do
  def extract_phone_number(%User{contact_info: contact_info}) do
    case contact_info do
      %ContactInfo{phone_number: phone_number} -> phone_number
      _ -> nil
    end
  end
end

iex(1)> user = %User{}
%User{contact_info: nil}
iex(2)> Test.extract_phone_number user
nil
iex(3)> user = %User{contact_info: nil}
%User{contact_info: nil}
iex(4)> Test.extract_phone_number user
nil
iex(5)> user = %User{contact_info: %ContactInfo{phone_number: nil}}
%User{contact_info: %ContactInfo{phone_number: nil}}
iex(6)> Test.extract_phone_number user
nil
iex(7)> user = %User{contact_info: %ContactInfo{phone_number: 1234567}}
%User{contact_info: %ContactInfo{phone_number: 1234567}}
iex(8)> Test.extract_phone_number user
1234567
```

It doesn't work like a Maybe monad, but it is a way to use pattern matching to extract a value from nested structs while handling nil. From what I have read so far (I am fairly new to Elixir myself) using pattern matching like this seems to be more idiomatic Elixir.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can get so far is with with the `ok_jose` application:

```
use OkJose

defmodule Person do
  defstruct [:name, :address]
end

defmodule Address do
  defstruct [:locale, :state]
end

defmodule Locale do
  defstruct [:number, :street, :city]
end

defmodule Main do
  def main do
    person = %Person{
      name: "Homer",
      address: %Address{
        locale: %Locale{
          number: 742,
          street: "Evergreen Terrace",
          city: "Springfield",
        },
        state: "???"
      }
    }

    person
    |> case do %{address: %{locale: %{city: city}}} -> city; _ -> nil end
    |> String.upcase
    |> String.reverse
    |> Pipe.if(&(!is_nil(&1)))
    |> IO.inspect
  end
end

Main.main
```